# Entity Framework 7 Migrations: ModelSnapshot and IMigrationMetadata

Tags: entity-framework-core

When one adds a migration using beta1 of EF7, they also get an implementation of IMigrationMetadata as well as a subclass of ModelSnapshot. I'm wondering, what touse classes are for. Where to find some information about this? Or can anyone post here some info about this?

Comment: I have a blog post planned describing some of the improvements to migrations in EF7. I'll be sure to post a link here when it's published.

Comment: Posted: [EF7 Migrations: Design-time](http://bricelam.net/2014/12/16/ef7-migrations-designtime.html)